# JSON Post to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post

Hi guys I am having an issue and have read over a few topics on here and still can't solve my problem.

I am building an API on rails 4.0 and I have a method in my controller, shown bellow:

```
def jsonApiSearch

  @firstName    = params[:fn]          #
  @lastName     = params[:ls]          #
  @eID          = params[:custid]      #
  @prod         = params[:prod]        #
  @classifation = params[:classifation]       #
  @status       = params[:status]      #
  @specialty    = params[:specialty]   #
  @aIDType      = params[:aIDType]     #
  @aID          = params[:aID]         #
  @address      = params[:address]     #
  @city         = params[:city]        #
  @state        = params[:state]       #
  @country      = params[:country]     #
  @postalCode   = params[:pc]          #
  @role         = params[:role]         
  @affiliation  = params[:affill]       
  @priorityRank = params[:pr]
  @strict       = params[:strict]  

  #do something with the data 
end
```

My Route File has the the following code:

```
post '/jsonsearch', to: 'api#jsonApiSearch'
```

So I then send a post request to the /jsonsearch endpoint.

I set the content type and the application/json, and then place this into the body as a this:

{"message": "Let's see if this works.","subject": "JSON via curl"}

I keep getting back a 422 Unprocessable Entity error.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

SOLVED:
Turns out that I left protect_from_forgery enabled, which was causing an issue. That is now fixed.

Comment: you should write your answer as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I left protect_from_forgery enabled, which was causing an issue. It is turned on be default and will stop any non-get methods from working without some sort of authorization in place. Turn it off and your post will start working.